# Order multiple where statements

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to order multiple statements by their id from one table, but I keep getting this error "mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in..."

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM news WHERE categorie IN ('sports', 'movies', 'politics') ORDED BY id DESC";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Should I group them first somehow?

Comment: Note the rather obvious typo. Turn on error checking

Comment: change `ORDED BY `

to ORDER BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For debugging php errors first consult with [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

At first: The function is deprecated. Do not build new code on deprecated functions as they will be removed in the future.

Second: See return values, it says:

> For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

That means your SQL query triggered an error and mysql_query returned false. Oh and your error points to mysql_fetch_array but your code example does not have any.

Now, where is the error? It is **syntax error**
Your query contains `ORDED BY` instead of `ORDER BY`

Comment: I was looking at the code for an hour, didn't notice the silly mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The $result is returning false hence it is throwing error message. 
Please you can check with die statment in the mysql query as below : 
`$result=mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: If categorie names would not contain 'sports' etc the query would not return boolean but an empty set. Your answer is invalid. The code returns boolean because the query has SQL error

Comment: Thanks Kyborek for pointing out. I was just looking die statment at the first step.